# razor pages DropDownListFor; How to set different background color for each item in Dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have one dropdown .This dropdown are bind from database with id, item
But I have in database 3 columns id, item and color.

for example

> ID:1 Item: Pen Color:red in the database
>   ID:2 Item: Pencil Color:orange in the database

What I need to do it's to set for each item the right  color from client side.
in this case the Background Color of the Item Pen will be red and 
the Background Color of the Item Pencil will be orange.

Thanks

`PageModel` class, properties for the `AssetList`:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    public SelectList AssetList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

then  `onGet()`:

```
var asset = from c in _context.Asset
                           select c;
AssetList = new SelectList(Asset, "ID", "Item");
```

and the page:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select asp-for="AssetCode" class="form-control"
        asp-items="@Model.AssetList">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: show us the code you already have, so we can at least advise based on something

Comment: place id for select as selectid and you may use the jquery like$('#selectid').children().each(
        function (){
            var cor = $(this).val();
                $(this).css('backgroundColor',cor);
            
        }
    );

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe you misunderstood me. The question is how can i set the existing color from the database for each item in the dropdownlist. I have in the database for each item background color. I need to display it in the dropdownlist. If I follow your example I have to read first the color for each Item and then set it. You just set the color whitout reading. My problem is how to read color from database and set it in the dropdownlist. I don't know how to do this with jquery or javascript or c#.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select asp-for="WhiteChoice">
        <option value="">Keuze witkleur...</option>
        @foreach(var li in Model.products.whitecolors)
        {
            <option value="@li.ProductAddedValue" style="background-color: @li.hexcolor">@li.Title</option>
        }
    </select>
```